# How to create a regular expression to exclude more files and folders in vue-cli default project?

Tags: regex, unit-testing, vue.js, mocha.js

I have a project created with vue-cli which uses mocha for unit testing (default setting). I want to write a unit test, but I fail with following setting:

My project folder:

[image]

I fail with the following error messages:

```
WARNING in ./src/assets/css/variables.styl
Module build failed: ParseError: /Users/kevin.hu/Documents/vreditor/src/assets/css/variables.styl:4:154
   1| // style-loader: Adds some css to the DOM by adding a <style> tag
   2|
   3| // load the styles
   4| var content = require("!!../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--12-1!../../../node_modules/stylus-loader/index.js??ref--12-2!./variables.styl");
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
   5| if(typeof content === 'string') content = [[module.id, content, '']];
   6| if(content.locals) module.exports = content.locals;
   7| // add the styles to the DOM
```

So I want to run the test skipping the assets folder or other ones. The default setting just excludes main.js. How to write a regular expression to acheive what I want?

Note: this is the default setting:

```
const srcContext = require.context('../../src', true, /^\.\/(?!main(\.js)?$)/)
srcContext.keys().forEach(srcContext)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
const srcContext = require.context('../../src', true, /^\.\/(?!main(\.js)?$|assets(?![^\/]))/)
```

It uses the same negative lookahead to exclude *assets*. `(?![^\/])` means *not followed by a character that isn't a slash*, in other words: followed by a slash or the end of the string.

If you want to exclude other folders, it is shorter to put `(?![^\/])` in factor using a non-capturing group:

```
/^\.\/(?!main(\.js)?$|(?:folder1|folder2|folder3)(?![^\/]))/
```